# changing collation settings in Visual Studio 2017

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2017, sql-server-data-tools

I've got a database project I'm working on in visual studio 2017.  I've set the collation to be Latin1_General_CI_AS for the database but unfortunately when I do a debug build with a post execution script that merges values (in my script) into one of the tables I get the error "Cannot resolve the collation conflict between "Latin1_General_CI_AS" and "SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS" in the equal to operation."

The only thing I can think of is that script is being read with a collation from some setting is Visual Studio.  I've checked the local database it has created and it has the Latin1_General_CI_AS collation.  Is there a setting I can change in VS2017?  Anyone have any other ideas?

Thanks

Comment: In your script, you are comparing two strings that I have to presume are coming from different tables, different databases, or different servers (or you're comparing with a temp table). That's the only cases where such an error is possible, and it just means that the two strings you're comparing have different collations. This typically happens when using temp tables. Can you show the SQL that is generating the error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I have found the server collation cannot be changed in the localdb for SQL database projects in visual studio.

From pmbAustin comment I was able to determine it was indeed a temp table causing the issue.  I've set the collation for the text columns in that temp table to use the database default and this has resolved the issue.

Thanks